# Laravel 5.7: New Accessor works great but is not recognisable in Repository Class (unknown column) despite of adding $appends to Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have a `class Order extends Model`.

I created an Accessor called `requiresApproval` that returns `true` or `false`.

```
public function getRequiresApprovalAttribute(): bool
{
    if ($some_physical_column_from_db === 'does not matter') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I have my `Order` model and I call `$order->requiresApproval` I get my boolean value. **Everything works great.**

However I need this accessor to appear on the list of attributes because I want to use it in my repository class in `where` condition within query.

So based on the official documentation, I added:

```
protected $appends = [
    'requires_approval',
];
```

but when I `dd()` my Order, this attribute is not on the list of attributes (while $appends property indicates the accessor is there).

[image]

Long story short:

When in my repository I call:

```
public function getOrdersEligibleToBeSendToOptions(): Collection
{
    $columns = [
        '*',
    ];

    return $this->model
        ->where('status_uuid', '<>', OrderStatusesInterface::STATUS_COMPLETED)
        ->where('requiresApproval', '=', true) // this fails
        // ->where('requires_approval', '=', true) // this fails as well
        ->get($columns);
}
```

I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I use my accessor within repository class?

Comment: I don't think you can use an accessor directly when querying data from the database. my guess would be for you to first get the data from the database and filter the obtained collection based on the accessor

Comment: Yeah , that's what I thought as a backup solution, I just thought that maybe this can be solved purely on the SQL level, but probably I will have to filter returned condition…

Comment: Can you not write the same condition in `where` or `whereRaw`?

Comment: You will obtain a collection from the database, You can then filter this collection based on the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this works, but the reason I don't like this solution is the fact that just half of the conditions are on the DB layer, the rest is by filtering what's already fetched.

If the query is going to return (let's say) thousand of records and filter returns just a few of them I personally see this as a huge waste of DB resource.

```
public function getOrdersEligibleToBeSendToOptions(): Collection
{
    $columns = [
        '*',
    ];

    $results = $this->model
        ->where('status_uuid', '<>', OrderStatusesInterface::STATUS_COMPLETED)
        ->get($columns);

    return $results->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return $value->requiresApproval === false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent queries work on the database fields, but you can use your accessor after fetching a colletion from the database like this.

Here is some good article about this:

https://medium.com/@bvipul/laravel-accessors-and-mutators-learn-how-to-use-them-29a1e843ce85

```
return $this->model
      ->where('status_uuid', '<>', OrderStatusesInterface::STATUS_COMPLETED)
      ->get($columns)
      ->filter(function ($row) {
           return $row->requires_approval === true;
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

The model virtual attributes cannot be used within queries. Perhaps a better approach would be to create a `scope` to enforce this constraint on a query:

```
class Order extends Model
{

    public function scopeRequiresApproval($query)
    {
        return $query->where('some_column', '>', 100);
    }
}
```

Then

```
return $this->model
        ->where('status_uuid', '<>', OrderStatusesInterface::STATUS_COMPLETED)
        ->requiresApproval()
        ->get($columns);
```